# How to paint a texture on top of a repeated texture?

Tags: texturing, materials

I would like to create a ground that has grass and a road in the middle using textures. For the grass, I downloaded an image and set it as a texture with **repetition**. For the road, I have another texture. Today, I learned how to use Texture Paint mode. It seems that I can paint the road if the grass texture was not repeated. But how can I paint the road texture on this repeated texture? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can mix both textures with a MixRGB, create a new image in the image editor and then paint a black and white mask in texture paint mode to be used in in the fac input, you can set everything and go into the LookDev or Material Preview to see the efect while painting.

Comment: Simple and powerful answer :D Thank you so much :)